# ASA8 - Do not have permission to grant permissions

Tags: powerbuilder, sybase-asa

I'm having a problem on my customer pc (and not on my own) when I run this embedded sql script in a Powerbuilder application on a ASA8 database. I use embedded scripts to modify database tables and add users:

```
ALTER TABLE LOADCON ADD LOADSALES_RATE NUMERIC(12,2);
```

It produces the following error:

```
SQLDBCODE: -121 - SQLSTATE = 42000
[Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Anywhere]Syntax error or access violation: Permission denied: you do not have permission to...
```

I have separate embedded code to add users and grand permissions - and these don't produce any errors:

```
sp_addlogin user_name, password
GRANT CONNECT TO user_name IDENTIFIED BY password
GRANT GROUP to DBA
GRANT MEMBERSHIP in group DBA to user_name
```

But when I run this:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON table_name TO user_name
```

it kicks up a similar error to the above:

```
SQLDBCODE: -121 - SQLSTATE = 42000
[Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Anywhere]Syntax error or access violation: Permission denied: you do not have permission to grant permissions on 'table_name'
```

When I execute this embedded script on my machine (windows7) logged on from a PB app to ASA8 using dba/sql it works with no fail errors (except user_names already exists) but running the same on a customer machine (windows8) the above fails with `SQLCODE = -1` , `SQLCA.SQLERRTEXT` messages as shown.

Any advise please.

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Permission differences are all about which account is currently logged on...

Is the Windows 8 machine also logging on as DBA/SQL?

And is this the same physical database, or are these two separate local ASA8 engines running their own .DB file?

Comment: Hi. 
- Yes, the Win8 PC also logged on as dba/sql.
- The same bd file but copied on 2 different machines... thus yes 2 different files on 2 different machines but one the copy of the other.
- the customer emailed me his db file. I installed in on my side, logged in with dba/sql and the sql in question executed with no errors.
- Could it be the customers win8 OS security somehow interferring with read/write access to the db file?

Comment: Well, if you didn't have read/write permissions on the .DB file (or the folder it's in), then I doubt the local ASA8 engine would even start.

Don't forget, ASA8 is LONG off of active maintenance.  I think it's from around 2001, so most definitely not certified or supported on Windows 8...